# sprintf string manupulation not working correctly in loadrunner

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am building a queryString like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char filters[300];
    char logicalAnd[5] = " and ";
    char orderNumberFilter[55];
    char punchOrderFilter[50];
    char jobsiteFilter[50];
    char frenteFilter[50];
    char statusFilter[23];

    char orderNumber[] = "pedidos";
    char punchOrder[] = "123456789";
    char jobsite[] = "65119415";
    char frente[] = "65119415";
    char status[] = "B";

    sprintf(orderNumberFilter, "OrderNum eq '%s'", orderNumber);
    sprintf(punchOrderFilter, "PurchOrder eq '%s'", punchOrder);
    sprintf(jobsiteFilter, "Jobsite eq '%s'", jobsite);
    sprintf(frenteFilter, "Frente eq '%s'", frente);
    sprintf(statusFilter, "Status eq '%s'", status);

    sprintf(filters, "%s%s%s%s%s%s", "&$filter=", orderNumberFilter, logicalAnd, punchOrderFilter, logicalAnd, jobsiteFilter);
    printf(filters);

    return 0;
}
```

And I am getting this output using an online compiller:

```
&$filter=OrderNum eq 'pedidos' and PurchOrder eq '123456789' and Jobsite eq '65119415'
```

But when i try the same code in loadrunner using `lr_output_message("filters: %s", filters);` to show the results, this is what I am getting:

```
&$filter=OrderNum eq 'pedidos' and &$filter=OrderNum eq 'pedidos'PurchOrder eq '123456789' and &$filter=OrderNum eq 'pedidos' and &$filter=OrderNum eq 'pedidos'PurchOrder eq '123456789'Lº¯L•¯L‹Jobsite eq '65119415'
```

I also tried a basic example I saw using strcpy:

```
sprintf(orderNumberFilter, "OrderNum eq '%s'", orderNumber);
sprintf(punchOrderFilter, "PurchOrder eq '%s'", punchOrder);
sprintf(jobsiteFilter, "Jobsite eq '%s'", jobsite);
sprintf(frenteFilter, "Frente eq '%s'", frente);
sprintf(statusFilter, "Status eq '%s'", status);

strcpy(filters, "&$filter=");
strcpy(filters, orderNumberFilter);
strcpy(filters, logicalAnd);
strcpy(filters, punchOrderFilter);
strcpy(filters, logicalAnd);
strcpy(filters, jobsiteFilter);

lr_output_message("filters: %s", filters);
```

And this is the output:

```
Jobsite eq '65119415'
```

So... whats going on with load runnner?

[image: screenshot]

*Replaced subsequents strcpy for strcat as  @Some programmer dude sugested

```
char filters[300];
char logicalAnd[5] = " and ";
char orderNumberFilter[55];
char punchOrderFilter[50];
char jobsiteFilter[50];
char frenteFilter[50];
char statusFilter[23];

char orderNumber[] = "pedidos";
char punchOrder[] = "123456789";
char jobsite[] = "65119415";
char frente[] = "65119415";
char status[] = "B";

sprintf(orderNumberFilter, "OrderNum eq '%s'", orderNumber);
sprintf(punchOrderFilter, "PurchOrder eq '%s'", punchOrder);
sprintf(jobsiteFilter, "Jobsite eq '%s'", jobsite);
sprintf(frenteFilter, "Frente eq '%s'", frente);
sprintf(statusFilter, "Status eq '%s'", status);

strcpy(filters, "&$filter=");
strcat(filters, orderNumberFilter);
strcat(filters, logicalAnd);
strcat(filters, punchOrderFilter);
strcat(filters, logicalAnd);
strcat(filters, jobsiteFilter);
```

Here is the output:

```
&$filter=OrderNum eq 'pedidos' and OrderNum eq 'pedidos'PurchOrder eq '123456789' and OrderNum eq 'pedidos'Jobsite eq '65119415'
```

It's closer but scrambled.

Comment: Instead of a series of `strcpy` call just keep the first, and then use `strcat`. But the main issue is that the `sprintf` call should work (if there's space enough in the buffer, same with the other `sprintf` calls in regards to the buffer size, is there space for the terminator as well? perhaps you should use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead?)

Comment: *And this is the output: `Jobsite eq '65119415'`*. That is because every `strcpy(filters, ...);` overwrites the previous, and you end up with `jobsiteFilter`.

Comment: Re the first part of the question. For what it's worth, your exact code in MSVC outputs `&$filter=OrderNum eq 'pedidos' and PurchOrder eq '123456789' and Jobsite eq '65119415'`

Comment: @Weather Vane I didn't say the code was wrong, what I am triying to achieve is how to make it work in loadrunner.

Comment: @Ziul please do not edit the code posted in response to comments. It makes the narrative hard to follow. The code you post is not supposed to be interactive here.

Comment: @Weather Vane alright, no more edits. It will stay like it is.

Comment: @Ziul oh sorry! You added the mods, no problem. I mistakenly thought you altered the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unterminated string in

```
char logicalAnd[5] = " and ";
```

If you write

```
char logicalAnd[] = " and ";
```

as you did with other string literals, the compiler will include the `'\0'` terminator. But you restricted the array length, and in this circumstance the compiler does not include the terminator, or issue warnings.

As it is, the behaviour is undefined when you pass what you think is a "string", but isn't, to string handling functions like `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Comment: You are right!, also, changing `logicalAnd[5]` to `logicalAnd[6]` fixes the issue too. Some amazing low level programming stuff going on here... I should had paid more attention to my C lectures when I was a student 11 years ago... I will pay more attention to null terminated strings from now on. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you but please follow my suggestion - `char logicalAnd[] = " and ";` like the other definitions - which do not specify a length.